# Объединить данные по столбцам в один без потерь в Excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Как можно сделать так, чтобы данные с разных столбцов слились в один, но без значений "Н\Д".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При использовании формулы =СУММЕСЛИМН(M1:T1;M1:T1;"<>#Н/Д") Некоторые данные не выводятся

[image]

Comment: Сложить суммой.

Comment: Получается "Н\Д"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Преобразовать текстовые числовые значения в число.

Копировать пустую ячейку, выделить диапазон, ПКМ на выделенном - *Спецвставка- Сложить*. Следует помнить, что при этом формат ячеек диапазона примет формат копированной ячейки.

2. Неправильный разделитель.

Если в настройках ситемы числовой раазделитель - запятая, то данные с точкой воспринимаются как текст. Разделитель перед суммирование нужно заменить.

Выделить диапазон, *Ctrl+H*, *НАЙТИ* `.` (точка) - *ЗАМЕНИТЬ* на `,` (запятая) - *Заменить_все*

3. После преобразования данных достаточно формулы

   `=СУММЕСЛИ(M2:T2;"<>#Н/Д")`
4. Если работать с данным правильно, то пункты 1 и 2 могут быть лишними:

--- нельзя допускать наличие ошибок на листе. Обходить *#Н/Д* в формулах, которые подтягивают данные. При отсутствии ошибок преобразовать текстовые значения в числа можно в формуле суммирования

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--M2:T2)
```

--- мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно. Наличие в диапазонах числовых данных и в текстовых, и в числовых форматах - следствие все той же неправильной подготовки данных. При нормально подготовленных достаточно простой функции

```
=СУММ(M2:T2)
```

Answer (score 1):

В ячейку U1 введите формулу

```
=СУММЕСЛИМН(M1:T1;M1:T1;"<>#Н/Д")
```

Или если складываете значения в столбце то измените диапазоны у формулы

Comment: Получилось, но вот некоторые данные не выводятся. Возможно из-за того, что они были сохранены как текст. Не знаете, что с этим можно поделать?

Comment: 1. В любую свободную ячейку поставьте цифру 1. 2. Скопируйте ее. 3. Выделите свои исходные данные (которые с числами и текстом) 4. На вкладке главная выберите вставить-специальная вставка, выберите операцию умножение, числа записанные как текст преобразуются в обычные числа